# a blinking arrow indicating a reply with more votes below

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface, hyperlinks

If the accepted answer to a question is very long, we need to scroll down whether the next reply has more votes or not. I would like to request SE software development team to add a blinking arrow indicating that there is another answer having more votes.

Comment: You can sort the answers by votes (there is a button at the bottom right of the answer)

Comment: @CarLaTeX that button still puts the accepted answer on the top of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [SOX Stack App](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/27724) provides a bunch of optional features, one being "an improvement to answer visibility" - a showcase of links to 5 other highest-ranking answers (by score) on that page.

[image]

Changing the sorting order (between active, oldest and votes) will give you a different list of 5 answers. Since our average answers-per-question count is under 2 (207,945 questions with 267,598 answers ~ 1.3 answers/question as of Nov 24, 2020) this approach will work for most posts.